# Stepwise summing from adjacent cell

Tags: excel, cumulative-sum

Summing down the way in excel. Im trying to calculate the total along a path in stepwise pieces, for example for each blank row I want the total from the left cell and add it to the total overall.
column 14 row 1 should be 3925.923, C14 R2 3925.923+1407.438, C14 R3 3925.923+1407.438 +1075.749 etc all the way to the bottom.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SUM()` formula like-

```
=SUM($A$1:$A1)
```

[image]

Comment: @AdarshBhardwaj If you find it working then please accept the answer (tick mark the answer).